# Symmetric powers of the standard representation

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I was just wondering whether there exists a nice way to decompose the symmetric powers of the standard representation of $S_n$, $(n-1,1)$. I know such a formula exists for alternating powers but I can not find anything for symmetric powers.

Thanks